# Xamarin Android Designer shows a black screen instead of the application interface

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Today I started to learn the world of application development for Android using the Xamarin platform for visual studio 2017. I followed Xamarin's official tutorials and videos on YouTube, when I opened my first project and went to the designer,the designer's screen was fully black. This doesn't happen in any guide or article I have read. Since I'm new, I don't have much idea where the problem might be, I'm attaching appropriate pictures.

My Visual Studio's Screen: [Desirable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnriL.png)

Xamarin tutorial's Screen: [Available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFpHv.png)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I'm so sorry.. the post was edited.

Comment: Try going to `Tools -> Options` and under `Environment -> General`(Which is the default), uncheck `Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance`.

Comment: didn't work :((

Comment: Can you include your full environment such as `Help->About Visual Studio` and your JDK version / Android SDK versions?

Comment: [Here is the issue report, you can follow it](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/164546/xamarin-android-designer-shows-a-black-screen-inst.html), I think this doesn't influence your application to run temporarily, if you just want to see it, you can copy it to Android Studio.

Comment: @JonDouglas https://image.prntscr.com/image/URn5IBXMScejxKZ1mFwYFA.png

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem, and I found a good solution :

Try going to Tools -> Options and under Xamarin-> Android UI Designer, uncheck the option "Enable accelerated rendering".

Just close every xaml which are opened, and reopen there ! enjoy ! (I hope)

Comment: Great answer. Seconded.

Comment: Works flawlessly!

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost make sure that you have the latest JDK version installed. I had the same issue with the designer and fixed it by upgrading to JDK 1.8.0.161.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I created a new layout. What worked for me was to close and reopen Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the same problem. Close Visual Studio and delete manualy the bin and obj folder from my project worked for me.