# Xamarin.Android designer is not displaying anything

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I am just started leaning the Xamarin using Visual Studio 2019. I've downloaded "Hello, Android" sample from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/hello-android/hello-android-quickstart but designer is not displaying anything.

See screenshot of Visual Studio Community 2019 [image: Visual Studio Community 2019] here.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps your problem is related to hardware acceleration in Android Designer. You can try the solution given by xNiux in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52253429/1106332.
Tools -> Options and under Xamarin-> Android UI Designer, uncheck the option "Enable accelerated rendering"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is just the case for Xamarin Previewer, it often has problems. And we apologize for the inconvenience. The xamarin development team is doing their best to address this issue and we are urging them to release the latest version as soon as possible.

Of course, you can also try other alternate tools ,e.g. `LiveXAML` and `Xamarin live reload`.

For more details, you can check:

https://www.livexaml.com/

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Xamarin.XamarinLiveReload

Comment: Thanks a lot Meloman and Jessie Zhang for the answer.  I downloaded and tried to install XamarinLivReload extension but it is throwing error.  here is the error from log : Searching for applicable products...
 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
- Found installed product - Global Location
 - Found installed product - Visual Studio Community 2019
 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products. \n LiveXAML is not also solving my problem.  Thanks

Comment: Well, what's the problem when you try LiveXAML ?